# Should I use <p> or <span> element for a single line of text?

Tags: html, text, markup

Sometime ago I read somewhere that one single line of text is considered a paragraph, therefore valid to be placed into a `<p>` element that *"represents a paragraph/block of text"*.

Browsing around this is confirmed by some examples that I've just found:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/p#Example_A

[http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/p](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/p#Example_A)

In my particular case I am making a `<form>` that includes some validation messages for each field and that are only meaningful to the user once they interact with the page.

For positioning purposes (`<p>` is a block element) would be easier to use `<p>` elements for these messages, but since `<span>` is a more generic and meaningless element I could use it too with `"display:block"` but I am not sure if I should do this instead.

Could you tell me what is the element to be used in this case?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 spec defines that the [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) "represents a paragraph", and a [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#paragraph) is defined as:

> A **paragraph** is typically a run of phrasing content that forms a block of text with one or more sentences that discuss a particular topic, as in typography, but can also be used for more general thematic grouping. For instance, an address is also a paragraph, as is a part of a form, a byline, or a stanza in a poem.

No-one can generally answer if you should use `p` or not, this depends on each particular case, and also your understanding of the content.

Now, if you think `p` may not be appropriate, why do you want to go with [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) when you are looking for a block element? Just use [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) instead.

Comment: Hi @unor, actually for the research I've done, this particular case, and for the suggestions received it here sounds like any of them would be fine which was my main doubt. The  <p> element gives in addition to its text paragraph representation the advantage of the default display: block feature so I gonna go for it, a div would be ok and valid HTML but to me is more an element that works to define sections of content rather than just defining only text on them. Thanks for your the insight.

Answer (score 1):

`SPAN` is kind of Styling tag only. it is being used when you are going to add a class by yourself and you don't need any un-wanted (Default) styles.

And `P` is which normally comes with default styling from a client browser and if you are using some pre-written styles (bootstrap etc).

Comment: sounds like <p> is the way to go in this case, <span> is more like a text placeholder with inline behavior and I would need to force it to position properly. Thank you.