# Wrapping anchor elements with text

Tags: html, seo, anchor, semantic-markup

If an anchor element has text (and only text), but is not part of a larger block of text, does it matter (e.g. semantics, SEO, maintenance) whether or not that anchor tag is wrapped by a paragraph element?

```
<!-- Wrapped -->
<p><a href=''>Link Description</a></p>

<!-- Standard -->
<a href=''>Link Description</a>
```

Looking at large websites, both ways appear to be popular. But are there any notable differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that `p` should only be used [for paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790815/1591669). If it’s not a paragraph, and you want to use such a wrapper, use `div` instead; if it is a paragraph, `p` should be used anyway.)

I can think of two cases where such a wrapper semantically matters (see below). Another good reason for using a wrapper is, of course, if the existing CSS/JS suggests/requires it (e.g., if the CSS author decided to style `div` elements, and an `a` without a `div` wrapper would break the layout).

#### Line breaks

User agents that don’t support author-provided CSS (like text browsers, feed readers, etc.) typically start a new line for elements like `div`, `p`, etc. (i.e., "block-level elements" in HTML 4), but not for elements like `span`, `a`, etc. ("inline elements").

So if you have something like this:

```html
<p>Teaser with some text.</p>
<a href="link">Read more</a>
<cite>John Doe</cite>
```

such a user agent might display the last two elements on the same line:

```
Teaser with some text.

Read more John Doe
```

while it might be preferable to have each on its own line:

```
Teaser with some text.

Read more

John Doe
```

So for this and similar cases a wrapping element (that typically creates a new line by default) should be used.

If the `a` is the only [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content) element (e.g., between two `p` elements), then this is not an issue, of course.

#### Unclosed `p`

If a `p` element has no closing tag (which is valid), a following `a` would become part of the `p`:

```html
<p>some text

<a href="link">Read more</a>
```

If closing the `p` is not an option, one would have to use a wrapper for the `a` (one that can’t be a child of `p`, e.g., a `div`).